# Fire hose like channel

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I would like to have a fire hose like channel, where it would be possible to write data that will be retrievable by **currently** connected clients. I would like an API that looks somehow like this :

```
-- I chose IO to illustrate, but any suitable monad such as STM would be fine
newFirehose :: SomeConfiguration -> IO (Firehose a)
ghReader :: Firehose a -> IO (FirehoseReader a)
closeReader :: FirehoseReader -> IO ()
broadcast :: Firehose a -> a -> IO ()
-- returns nothing for closed readers
receive :: FirehoseReader a -> IO (Maybe a)
```

The requirements I came up with are :

- It should be possible to add and remove clients at will, which means something like `dupXXX` and `closeXXX`, but where closing doesn't terminate everything.
- It is acceptable to have an interface with read-only and write-only types.
- It should use a bounded amount of memory.
- A client that does not read from the fire hose, or that is slow, must not block the other clients.
- It is acceptable to discard values.
- In the absence of performance problems, all clients should receive the same data.

I don't think there is an already written Chan-like module for that, and it doesn't seem trivial to write. Here are my questions :

- Is there already something out there that would be usable ?
- Am I missing a crucial requirement ?
- Can someone share pointers or ideas on how to write such a structure ?

Edit : this is actually a very useful construct. Here is what I would use it for : it happens that I have several message busses in my production system. I would like to be able to dynamically connect remote clients to this bus in order to inspect some messages, while they are in transit, in real time. This is useful for debugging and reporting.

Comment: Have you looked at `Control.Concurrent.Chan`?  It has `dupChan` which lets you safely duplicate the channel to another client.  There might be some other semantics you have to take into consideration, but I know it's possible with that module.

Comment: Yes I did, and it just fails at all my other requirements. It is unbounded, you can't close the duplicated channels and it is not broadcasting but distributing.

Comment: I haven't thought this through carefully (no answer), but would a wrapper on top of a `[Chan a]` work just fine?

Comment: Actually with a bounded chan type it might work ... thanks.

Comment: Not sure how this could have been "less broad", as I actually needed a generic tool here. However the answer I had gave me enough pointer to write the code, so I suppose this can be closed / deleted / whatever is being done with questions that are not respecting the rules.

Comment: And here is the current version of the result : https://github.com/bartavelle/stm-firehose/blob/master/Control/Concurrent/STM/Firehose.hs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will need some sort of IORefs to hold data and lists of clients.  One possible solution would be to keep a list of client handlers ([a->IO()] functions inserted by clients to "subscribe").  This has the advantage of not needing to store the data itself anywhere once the broadcast is finished, thus adhering to the 'bounded memory' requirement.  Your `subscribe` and `broadcast` functions would be pretty simple to write, they would just add a function to the list, and iterate through the list calling each function.  The downside is that once a broadcast is finished, the data would be gone....

Another possibility would be to use IORefs to store the actual data.  In this approach, you would keep a list of `[a]`'s and add to the list whenever something is broadcasted.  Data could be sent using push (in which case you will need a separate list of [IO()] functions corresponding to the clients anyway), or pull, in which case you will need to tag each `a` with a sequence number or timestamp (which clients would use to determine what is new).  I would avoid the pull case whenever possible (it usually involves polling, which is evil).

Honestly, if you were a client coming to me with this spec, I would push you a bit harder to determine if the spec is really what you want....  Without knowing more about the problem, I can't say for sure, but it almost sounds like you want these clients to be remote, in which case a tcp/ip server/client model might be warranted.  If this is the case, ignore everything I said above, and you will probably want to add a database, and need to settle on a communication protocol.

Or perhaps you need something in the middle- Clients running in another process, but on the same computer.  For this case, linked libraries or Microsoft COM objects (wrapped around a database, or even just a few files) might fit the bill.

I suspect all the downvoting is because the specs aren't that clear, as any of these very different answers that I have given you could possibly answer the requirements.  (I wan't one of the downvoters).

Comment: This gave me food for thought. I will try to implement something like you described in your first chapter with STM bounded channels. I also tried to clarify the use case for this particular structure ...